# How to measure the magnitude of difference between two gaussian distributions? Specifically with rates of DNA mutations

Tags: distributions, histogram, biostatistics

As the title says I want to quantify the difference in the rates of sequence change between genes. When I measure the mutation rates between my subgenomes I can determine a significant but slight difference via wilcoxon test (the distributions are gaussian but with tails). This ends up being true for many of the different types of mutations I measure, but visually I can see that different types differ in the magnitude of their difference. What is the best way to quantify the magnitude of the difference? I don't think comparing the p-values is right, and the subtraction of the median seems crude but maybe I am overthinking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"*the distributions are gaussian but*" -- the inclusion of 'but' means "the distributions are not Gaussian".

If you think there's a location-shift*, you can produce an estimate of its size from the Wilcoxon, since it has an associated estimate (Hodges-Lehmann) and confidence interval for the population quantity. (It will only estimate the difference in medians if it is a location shift alternative. But then, equally, if means exist, it will also estimate the difference in means.)

* you can adapt the approach to estimate a scale-shift if you think that's more like what's going on.

What you should use depends on what you want to find out and what you're prepared to assume.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification and advice, works perfectly